# Recommend a Software for documenting work/research

Tags: windows

Need a software for documenting my work & research. I was considering to use blog engine but then I don't want to be playing around with backing up the databases and the matter separately.

The specifications for the software would be:

1) To catalogue work by categories, tags and date.

2) Easy editing and drawing features

3) Easily incorporate saved html files into matter I'm writing, with the formatting and pictures. (probably use the mht format, don't want to be wasting timeformatting html pages) Would like the html pages to be directly displayed in the software and not opened on demand

Software should be for Windows. Any recommendations?

4) Language tools could be an addition but only an optional feature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't like OneNote, you might have a look at [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) instead. Prominent tagging support (I'll concede that it makes them more noticeable than OneNote does) and shares the ability to easily clip or copy/paste web content.

Other pluses included the price (there's a free offering) and the easy ability to sync to multiple computers and [a bit limited] web access.

Comment: Evernote is really cool but is OneNote the only alternative which is completely offline. Wish OneNote was more simplistic like Evernote. Evernote is so much more user friendly!

Comment: You don't *have* to sync to the Evernote servers if you want to stay offline. That's an option you control when you create each notebook (local only or sync). Even if the notebook is synced, the data is local so you can still use it when not connected to the 'net.

Answer (score 5):

[OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/default.aspx).

Comment: but onenote does not allow tagging and html files have to be opened externally. One note is currently what I'm using for most of my work, sorry that i didn't mention it in the post above

Comment: Onenote fully supports tagging and filtering by tags -- but many folks haven't found the tags or noticed that you can customize them.

Comment: any links to the same?

Comment: Oh, and use the onenote tray app to quickly/easily capture formatted web pages.

Comment: @Rogue - here's a "Tips & Tricks" article that talks about tags and such: http://blogs.msdn.com/onenotetips/archive/2008/05/07/note-tags.aspx

Comment: well I use the tray app to get the pics and manually copy the text now

Comment: (my last rebuttal, I promise!) Configured correctly, nothing needs to be manual in OneNote :-)

Answer (score 2):

Recently I began using [FlatPress](http://www.flatpress.org/home/) on a private directory on my web host's server for documenting my work notes.  (Previously, I just did it with word processing software on my work desktop, but a new job has me working in multiple locations).  Thus far, I've been happy with FlatPress.

I avoided the "normal" online note taking sites because I wasn't thrilled with the idea of putting my stuff in a space where I wasn't sure how much control I'd have.  In part, this was because one recommendation I found on the web as "the best" had a one page site that said, essentially "Going out of business, get your data now or lose it!"  (I know the owner of my web host personally, so have no fear that they are going to go out of business without my knowledge, or that they'll misuse my data.)

FlatPress is a blog engine, but it uses plain text files instead of an SQL database to store its entries.  Thus back ups could be as simple as copying the contents of the appropriate sub-directory (fp-contents, assuming a default install).

If you are running a web server with PHP, FlatPress should be very easy to install:  just download, copy into the directory where you want your blog/notes, decompress, and then navigate to that directory with your web browser and click on install/setup (I don't remember the exact term they use).  I did this on a home PC running Windows with [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) before setting it up on the web server.  If you're on Linux, you'll also have to make the contents directory writable before you do the install via the web.

Comment: As a small correction regarding paragraph 2: OneNote is desktop software, no "cloud" or vendor dependencies. If Microsoft goes out of business (!) you'll still have your data. You may have meant Evernote, but even in that case your data is still stored locally.

Comment: @Chris_K:  Thanks for pointing that out, I haven't used either.  I've modified the answer to remove the error.

Answer (score 2):

Found an amazing application for one note: [One Note Calender](http://www.einsteintech.net/apps/DisplayApp.aspx?path=publish&app=OneNoteCalendar)

- Features Include:

  - Month, week, and day views similar to Outlook’s calendar
  - Preview pane shows you the contents of the page
  - Quick access to any page by double clicking the calendar
  - Create new pages
  - Full screen mode and consideration for low-resolutions
  - Modern look and feel with Vista Aero Glass support
  - Automatic layout switching for Tablet PC portrait mode

[image]

Comment: Oh say, that's really quite cool. nice find!

Answer (score 2):

Try [TiddlyWiki!](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) all you need is a web browser.

Comment: Tiddly Wiki is actually also very cool! I used to used Cinta Notes earlier keeping quick notes of stuff and searching within tags, but now I'm totally switching to Tiddly wiki for that purpose now! I'm also trying out D3 its a spin off from tiddly wiki but looks more promising with reminders and all! Cheers!